# is Open GL a Overkill for a 2d Card Game?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, core-animation, playing-cards

I was just have an idea of creating a card game and I was just thinking whether to use OpenGl or CoreAnimation.Can you please tell me whether it would be a bit of a overkill to use OpenGL for s 2D card game.Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's hard to say without knowing more. You can get pretty far using CALayers, images or drawing with quartz for the cards though. It really depends on the level of visual effects you are considering. If it's just moving cards around, then I'd say use layers.

Answer (score 2):

Might want to check out [GeekGameBoard](http://mooseyard.com/hg/hgwebdir.cgi/).

"A small framework for building board and card games, using Apple's Core Animation."

Answer (score 0):

Given that Core Animation uses OpenGL for rendering, you probably won't notice much of a difference in performance or memory usage. I don't think that you would gain anything by using OpenGL. Plus, you would have to handle all the animations on your own, as opposed to the prebuilt "set it and forget it" technique in Core Animation.