# iPhone - Need some reference code for card game

Tags: iphone, mahjong

I am going to build a card game. Game will be like MahJong.
I want some reference code or link to start with. If you have any, then please share it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at Jens Alfke's [GeekGameBoard](http://mooseyard.com/hg/hgwebdir.cgi/) open source framework, which uses Core Animation to enable board or card games.  You might also want to check out the following questions:

- [Are there any Open-source iPhone games around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365947/are-there-any-open-source-iphone-games-around)
- [iPhone board game: OpenGL ES or CoreGraphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082511/iphone-board-game-opengl-es-or-coregraphics)
- [is Open GL a Overkill for a 2d Card Game ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566874/is-open-gl-a-overkill-for-a-2d-card-game)

Answer (score 1):

This site:

[Mah-Jong for Linux, Unix, MacOS and Windows](http://mahjong.julianbradfield.org/)

seems to contains links to just about every other site. Also there is source to download. Were you interested in the solitaire game or doing a 4-player networked thing?